# trying to run a get and a post with aiohttp

Tags: python

this is my code i am trying to do 2 requests a get and a post with async i get this error now:

async with session.post(

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'post'

any idea how i can run 2 requests using async and parsing the data?

````
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(
                'https://login.yahoo.com',
                ) as login:
            crumb = (await login.text()).partition('crumb" value="')[-1].partition('"')[0]
            acrumb = (await login.text()).partition('name="acrumb" value="')[-1].partition('" />')[0]
            session = (await login.text()).partition('sessionIndex" value="')[-1].partition('"')[0]
            print(acrumb)
            print(session)
            print(crumb)
        async with session.post(
            'SECONDURL',
        ) as check:
            print(await check.text())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line:

```py
session = (await login.text()).partition('sessionIndex" value="')[-1].partition('"')[0]
```

You're overwriting your session variable with this variable also named session.  I would change the variable name in the above line to something like:

```py
session_index = (await login.text()).partition('sessionIndex" value="')[-1].partition('"')[0]
```

---

```py
async def main():
    # you create a variable named session here
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            ...
            
            # you're mistakenly overwriting the session variable here
            session = (await login.text()).partition('sessionIndex" value="')[-1].partition('"')[0]
            ...
```

Comment: youre a life saver my brain just popped ty

Comment: No problem! Since this answered your question, would you mind selecting this as the "correct answer," in case anyone else encounters a similar issue, they can quickly find this post :)